# @ Sign with PHP and SQL Statements causing errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm working with a PHP site right now that connects to a database and selects off 1 of our tables to compare information. Currently we are running into an issue with the @ sign when comparing our email with a record in the table.

Here is exactly what is happening:

We are using a SELECT statement to compare the variable $Email to find out what is the associated ID for the account. The problem is when comparing with $Email and we have turned error reporting on we can see that the @hotmail.com is causing an error by SQL syntax standards.

```
$id = "SELECT idaccount FROM `animator`.`account` WHERE email = $Email";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $id) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
```

The outcome is the following:

```
    Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your     MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.com' at line 1
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Use quote around $Email as ='$Email'

Comment: and to be safe you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $Email)` instead of `$Email`. The single quotes before and after should stay so it looks like `"...'".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $Email)."'..."`

Comment: Thank you Salim! Such a rookie mistake!!! Sorry for the waste of time guys and appreciate the responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose the $Email value in single quotes, so the generated statement looks like this:

```
SELECT idaccount FROM `animator`.`account` WHERE email = 'something@hotmail.com'
```

Even better, you should prepare the statement and bind the value of $Email. Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Adding the prepared statement after testing has been completed for the database. We are just trying to get all working and then will switch over to prepared statements for SQL injection protection. Thanks for the help guys!